# Expressão Regular para senha

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação de senha forte em javascript. Inicialmente quero verificar se na string há a ocorrência de 02 números nas seguintes condições:

1. "12vvv": dois números seguidos ou mais de qualquer coisa retornando true
2. "1a1a": dois números separados ou mais retornando true
3. Deve retornar true em todos casos em que o texto contiver 02 números ou mais, independentemente de seu posicionamento.

Consegui a expressão abaixo que retorna true somente no caso 2 ("1a1a"):

```
/(\d{1}).(\d{1})/.test("a1a1")
```

Mas melhor opção foi sem expressão regular:

```
  function hasTwoNumber(text) {
    var arr        = text.split(""),
        tamanho    = arr.length,
        qtd = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
      if (/[0-9]/.test(arr[i])) {
        qtd++;
      }
    }

    return qtd > 1;
  }

console.log(hasTwoNumber("1a1a")); //true
console.log(hasTwoNumber("11aa")); //true
```

Gostaria de obter esse mesmo resultado com expressão regular. Alguém conhece uma expressão regular que atenda essas condições?

Comment: Dois números seguidos no 'meio' ou final da string da true também? exemplo `a22a` ou `aa22`?

Comment: Para deixar mais claro preciso que atenda o seguinte caso: a expressão regular deve obrigatoriamente identificar se a expressão tenha 02 números, obrigatoriamente, independente de ser sequencial ou não. O importante é identificar 02 números.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um jeito diferente:

```js
var a = '1a11aa1'.match(/\d.*\d+/g) != null;
console.log(a);

var b = 'a1a11'.match(/\d.*\d+/g) != null;
console.log(b);

var c = '1aaaa1'.match(/\d.*\d+/g) != null;
console.log(c);

var d = 'aaaa1'.match(/\d.*\d+/g) != null;
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Orraaa! É exatamente isso que eu quero!

Comment: Nessa expressão deu erro: `/^[\D]*\d[\D]*\d[\D]*$/.test('a1a11');`

Comment: @adrianosymphony deu não, veja de novo, editei a resposta e adicionei o teste no final.

Comment: Editei a questão para melhorar o resultado. Preciso forçar que a senha tenha 02 números no mínimo (ou mais). O meu intuito é que usuário tenha 02 números na senha ou mais. Ficou mais claro a minha intenção?

Comment: @adrianosymphony A nova edição muda o sentido da pergunta original, mas vou editar a resposta. Só toma cuidado na hora de perguntar, pois isso bagunça todas as respostas postadas antes da edição.

Comment: @adrianosymphony editado, vê se tá funcionando do jeito que você quer agora.

Comment: entendido, vou tentar evitar essas condições do que é permitido nas próximas questões.

Comment: Perfeito, atendeu perfeitamente meus problemas! Somente adaptei na minha função com a seguinte expressão: `!!'1a11aa1'.match(/\d.*\d+/g)`

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar a seguinte regex `/\d.\d|\d{2}./` ela diz que deve casar um número seguido de qualquer coisa e depois outro número ou (`|`) dois números seguidos de qualquer coisa.

Exemplos:

```
/\d.\d|\d{2}./.test('1bab22') //false, não tem nada depois dos dois números seguidos
/\d.\d|\d{2}./.test('1b1') //true, casa o primeiro padrão (lado esquerdo)
/\d.\d|\d{2}./.test('1baaa') //false
/\d.\d|\d{2}./.test('11') //false
/\d.\d|\d{2}./.test('111') //true, devido ao ponto casar qualquer coisa
```

Caso seja necessário retornar false para três números seguidos troque o ponto por `\D` que significa não dígito.

```
/\d\D\d|\d{2}\D/.test('111') //false
```

Pode identificar 2 ou mais números com `'2aaaa1a'.match(/\d+/g)`, nesse caso a abordagem muda de validar para capturar e depois verificar se bate com o esperado.

```
var temNumero = '2aaaa1a'.match(/\d+/g);
if(temNumero.length >=2){
   console.log('válido');
}else{
   console.log('não atende o padrão');
}
```

Comment: como comentado acima, eu preciso que identifique se tem 02 números no mínimo no texto em quaisquer posições. Não consegui encontrar nada parecido com isso com expressão regular.

Comment: @adrianosymphony a regex falhou em algum exemplo? posso corrigir

Comment: Nessa condição ela falha: `/\d.\d|\d{2}./.test('1bab1') `. pode corrigir sim :)

Comment: @adrianosymphony adicionei uma correção.

Comment: funcionou certinho. Valeu pela contribuição